# IdentityServer4: signin callback returns 404 status code - UserInfo endpoint not triggered

Tags: c#, identityserver4

For some time now I've been trying to setup a project with IdentityServer4. I've come a long way, but now in the final stage I'm getting a `404` statuscode when IdentityServer takes me back to the web application (`https://localhost:44384/signin-central?code=...&scope=...&state=...`). First I was using the `InMemoryClients` etc, but now the data is sourced from the database and I had to do some refactoring.

I've been analysing the errors in the output window and updating my code accordingly. But with the code I have now, I'm not getting any errors anymore in my Output (with LogLevel set to `Information`).

Also I'm not keen on modifying the `DefaultChallengeScheme`, because this restricts you rightaway when you plan to have multiple OAuth providers in the future.

## Code

This is The important code of the Client application

Application Startup

```
public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services
            .AddAuthentication(options => {
                //options.DefaultScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                //options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            }).AddCookie(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/AccessDenied");
            }).AddOAuth<CentralOptions, CentralHandler>("central", options => {
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "https://localhost:44359";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.ClientId = "SsoApplicationClient";
                options.ClientSecret = "qsdfghjklm";

                //options.Scope.Add("openid");
                //options.Scope.Add("profile");
                //options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("weatherforecasts.read");
                options.Scope.Add("weatherforecasts.write");

                options.UsePkce = true;

                //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("email", )
            }).AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44359";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "SsoApplicationClient";
                options.ClientSecret = "qsdfghjklm";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("weatherforecasts.read");
                options.Scope.Add("weatherforecasts.write");

                //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("website", "website");

                options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = async (info) => {
                    // This is never hit
                };
            });
        services
            .AddIdentity<Entities.User, Entities.Role>(options => {
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SsoApplicationContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services
            .AddDbContext<SsoApplicationContext>()
            .AddScoped<Repositories.IAccountRepository, Repositories.AccountRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        ...
    }
}
```

CentralOptions

```
public class CentralOptions : OAuthOptions {
    public CentralOptions() {
        CallbackPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/signin-central");
        AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://localhost:44359/connect/authorize";
        TokenEndpoint = "https://localhost:44359/connect/token";
        UserInformationEndpoint = "https://localhost:44359/connect/userinfo";
    }
}
```

Here I've overridden the methods to check what methods are being called, and what aren't. Everything below the comment line is never called.

CentralHandler

```
public class CentralHandler : OAuthHandler<CentralOptions> {
    public CentralHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CentralOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) {
    }
    protected override async Task InitializeEventsAsync() {
        await base.InitializeEventsAsync();
    }
    protected override async Task InitializeHandlerAsync() {
        await base.InitializeHandlerAsync();
    }
    protected override string ResolveTarget(string scheme) {
        var result = base.ResolveTarget(scheme);
        return result;
    }
    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties) {
        await base.HandleChallengeAsync(properties);
    }
    protected override void GenerateCorrelationId(AuthenticationProperties properties) {
        base.GenerateCorrelationId(properties);
    }
    protected override string BuildChallengeUrl(AuthenticationProperties properties, string redirectUri) {
        var challengeUrl = base.BuildChallengeUrl(properties, redirectUri);
        return challengeUrl;
    }
    protected override string FormatScope() {
        var scope = base.FormatScope();
        return scope;
    }
    protected override string FormatScope(IEnumerable<string> scopes) {
        var scope = base.FormatScope(scopes);
        return scope;
    }
    // Everything below this line is never called
    protected override async Task<object> CreateEventsAsync() {
        var events = await base.CreateEventsAsync();
        return events;
    }
    protected override async Task<HandleRequestResult> HandleAccessDeniedErrorAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties) {
        var result = await base.HandleAccessDeniedErrorAsync(properties);
        return result;
    }
    protected override async Task HandleForbiddenAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties) {
        await base.HandleForbiddenAsync(properties);
    }
    protected override async Task<HandleRequestResult> HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync() {
        var result = await base.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync();
        return result;
    }
    public override async Task<bool> HandleRequestAsync() {
        var result = await base.HandleRequestAsync();
        return result;
    }
    public override async Task<bool> ShouldHandleRequestAsync() {
        var result = await base.ShouldHandleRequestAsync();
        return result;
    }
    protected override bool ValidateCorrelationId(AuthenticationProperties properties) {
        var result = base.ValidateCorrelationId(properties);
        return result;
    }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(ClaimsIdentity identity, AuthenticationProperties properties, OAuthTokenResponse tokens) {
        var endpoint = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(Options.UserInformationEndpoint, "access_token", tokens.AccessToken);
        var response = await Backchannel.GetAsync(endpoint, Context.RequestAborted);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException($"An error occurred when retrieving Facebook user information ({response.StatusCode}). Please check if the authentication information is correct and the corresponding Facebook Graph API is enabled.");
        }

        var payload = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        var context = new OAuthCreatingTicketContext(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), properties, Context, Scheme, Options, Backchannel, tokens, payload.RootElement);
        context.RunClaimActions();

        await Events.CreatingTicket(context);

        return new AuthenticationTicket(context.Principal, context.Properties, Scheme.Name);
    }
    protected override async Task<OAuthTokenResponse> ExchangeCodeAsync(OAuthCodeExchangeContext context) {
        var result = await base.ExchangeCodeAsync(context);
        return result;
    }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() {
        var result = await base.HandleAuthenticateAsync();
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the important code of the IdentityServer application

Startup

```
public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddAuthentication(options => { });
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services
            .AddDbContext<SsoCentralContext>()
            .AddScoped<Repositories.IAccountRepository, Repositories.AccountRepository>()
            .AddScoped<Services.IAccountService, Services.AccountService>();

        services.AddIdentity<Entities.User, Entities.Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SsoCentralContext>();

        var isBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();
        isBuilder
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddOperationalStore<SsoCentralContext>(identityServerOptions => {
                identityServerOptions.ConfigureDbContext = (builder) => builder
                    .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=SsoCentral;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
            }).AddConfigurationStore<SsoCentralContext>(identityServerOptions =>
                identityServerOptions.ConfigureDbContext = (builder) => builder
                    .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=SsoCentral;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0")
            ).AddAspNetIdentity<Entities.User>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("connect/authorize")) {
                // Inspect the parameters of the Authorization request here
            }
            await next();
        });

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

SsoCentralContext

```
internal class SsoCentralContext : IdentityDbContext<Entities.User, Entities.Role, string>, IPersistedGrantDbContext, IConfigurationDbContext {
    ...
}
```

AccountController

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller {
    private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IEventService events;
    public AccountController(...) { ... }

    [HttpGet("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromQuery] string returnUrl) {
        var context = await interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
        return View(new ViewModels.Account.LoginVM {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
            User = new Dtos.Dtos.User {
                UserName = context?.LoginHint,
            }
        });
    }

    [HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginPost([FromForm] ViewModels.Account.LoginVM model) {
        var request = await interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(redirectUrl);
        try {
            var user = await accountRepository.Login(model.User.Email, model.Password);
            await events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(model.User.UserName, model.User.Id, model.User.UserName, clientId: request?.Client.ClientId));
            var isUser = new IdentityServer4.IdentityServerUser(model.User.Id) {
                DisplayName = model.User.UserName,
                AdditionalClaims = new[] {
                    new System.Security.Claims.Claim("sub", model.User.Id),
                    new System.Security.Claims.Claim("email", model.User.Email),
                    new System.Security.Claims.Claim("name", model.User.UserName),
                }
            };
            await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(isUser);

            if (request != null) {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            } else if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl)) {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            } else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl)) {
                return Redirect("~/");
            } else {
                throw new System.Exception("Invalid return url");
            }
        } catch (System.Exception ex) {
            await events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(loginEx.Email, "invalid credentials", clientId: request?.Client.ClientId));
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

## Setup

To debug the code:

```
git clone https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO.git
cd SSO/Application/Sso.Application.Data
dotnet ef database update --project ..\Sso.Application.Data --context SsoApplicationContext
cd ../../Central/Sso.Central.Data
dotnet ef database update --project ..\Sso.Central.Data --context SsoCentralContext
```

Run the SQL-script at SSO.Central.Data/Sql/CreateClient.sql

Or instead of all of the above, you can restore the `dacpac`s located at the `/dacpac` folder.

Set following startup projects:

- Sso.Central
- Sso.Application

Here is a demo of what's happening

[image: Demo of the IdentityServer application]

And here's the cutout of the Output window:

```
IdentityServer4.Startup: Information: Starting IdentityServer4 version 4.1.2+997a6cdd643e46cd5762b710c4ddc43574cbec2e
IdentityServer4.Startup: Information: Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: C:\Users\Pieterjan De Clippel\source\repos\SSO\Central\Sso.Central
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Login Url: /Account/Login
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Logout Url: /Account/Logout
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: ConsentUrl Url: /consent
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Error Url: /home/error
IdentityServer4.Startup: Debug: Error Id Parameter: errorId
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter: Trace: No endpoint entry found for request path: /
Sso.Application.CentralHandler: Debug: HandleChallenge with Location: https://localhost:44359/connect/authorize?client_id=SsoApplicationClient&scope=weatherforecasts.read%20weatherforecasts.write&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44384%2Fsignin-central&code_challenge=HawX6uXjjANMQJQbhwsxi5zlsFrQKzGzOiyefqEbfnI&code_challenge_method=S256&state=CfDJ8PC7ZLg_v2RDsl0VaXUuuT9WNuyCeQha-k3ea6NLsX65PkYCYTKtf9EK-wHqKcvECq5o6zsSVViHYi3gw66FydCTo_YImAwSpM7ShCcajz-Otdo0V8btKv-PtRLPZ2xoy1WBK90ZqAYk-EvZl59PUWBAJRaiU7VVkD8kV2YdY6wkQzwJJYA8qYQSJFgz-cMTwrYsZOzVjMx1lkHTVpyCZ9Lg48p5wBqN0y6R49yWIuDfLu3_7vAivlTJdgcXz9NT9HVeu89V2afjFxJLTQa2igeympC7JO-HRhdK5Zr-GM538kMAjZz5OW8dRWzKo-dX6rHSy3DC4hgaNXLuPK4b5qgStG4Wi4U5PH0LE9flO4bP; and Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.central.vhEd_no3ibUFd7fiocNPiZ25zTfFWfbuuM8BVh6LUMo=N; expires=Mon, 15 Nov 2021 20:47:22 GMT; path=/signin-central; secure; samesite=none; httponly.
Sso.Application.CentralHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: central was challenged.
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter: Debug: Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter: Debug: Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Debug: Start authorize request
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Debug: No user present in authorize request
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Start authorize request protocol validation
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore: Debug: SsoApplicationClient found in database: True
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Trace: Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Debug: client configuration validation for client SsoApplicationClient succeeded.
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Checking for PKCE parameters
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found  identity scopes in database
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found weatherforecasts API resources in database
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found weatherforecasts.read, weatherforecasts.write scopes in database
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Trace: Authorize request protocol validation successful
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Debug: ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{
  "ClientId": "SsoApplicationClient",
  "ClientName": "SsoApplicationClient",
  "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44384/signin-central",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "https://localhost:44384/signin-central"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "RequestedScopes": "weatherforecasts.read weatherforecasts.write",
  "State": "CfDJ8PC7ZLg_v2RDsl0VaXUuuT9WNuyCeQha-k3ea6NLsX65PkYCYTKtf9EK-wHqKcvECq5o6zsSVViHYi3gw66FydCTo_YImAwSpM7ShCcajz-Otdo0V8btKv-PtRLPZ2xoy1WBK90ZqAYk-EvZl59PUWBAJRaiU7VVkD8kV2YdY6wkQzwJJYA8qYQSJFgz-cMTwrYsZOzVjMx1lkHTVpyCZ9Lg48p5wBqN0y6R49yWIuDfLu3_7vAivlTJdgcXz9NT9HVeu89V2afjFxJLTQa2igeympC7JO-HRhdK5Zr-GM538kMAjZz5OW8dRWzKo-dX6rHSy3DC4hgaNXLuPK4b5qgStG4Wi4U5PH0LE9flO4bP",
  "PromptMode": "",
  "SessionId": "",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "SsoApplicationClient",
    "scope": "weatherforecasts.read weatherforecasts.write",
    "response_type": "code",
    "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44384/signin-central",
    "code_challenge": "HawX6uXjjANMQJQbhwsxi5zlsFrQKzGzOiyefqEbfnI",
    "code_challenge_method": "S256",
    "state": "CfDJ8PC7ZLg_v2RDsl0VaXUuuT9WNuyCeQha-k3ea6NLsX65PkYCYTKtf9EK-wHqKcvECq5o6zsSVViHYi3gw66FydCTo_YImAwSpM7ShCcajz-Otdo0V8btKv-PtRLPZ2xoy1WBK90ZqAYk-EvZl59PUWBAJRaiU7VVkD8kV2YdY6wkQzwJJYA8qYQSJFgz-cMTwrYsZOzVjMx1lkHTVpyCZ9Lg48p5wBqN0y6R49yWIuDfLu3_7vAivlTJdgcXz9NT9HVeu89V2afjFxJLTQa2igeympC7JO-HRhdK5Zr-GM538kMAjZz5OW8dRWzKo-dX6rHSy3DC4hgaNXLuPK4b5qgStG4Wi4U5PH0LE9flO4bP"
  }
}
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator: Trace: ProcessInteractionAsync
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator: Information: Showing login: User is not authenticated
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Trace: End authorize request. result type: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.LoginPageResult
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Trace: Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.LoginPageResult
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter: Trace: No endpoint entry found for request path: /Account/Login
IdentityServer4.Services.OidcReturnUrlParser: Trace: returnUrl is valid
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Start authorize request protocol validation
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore: Debug: SsoApplicationClient found in database: True
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Trace: Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Debug: client configuration validation for client SsoApplicationClient succeeded.
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Checking for PKCE parameters
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found  identity scopes in database
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found weatherforecasts API resources in database
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found weatherforecasts.read, weatherforecasts.write scopes in database
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Trace: Authorize request protocol validation successful
IdentityServer4.Services.OidcReturnUrlParser: Trace: AuthorizationRequest being returned
IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultIdentityServerInteractionService: Trace: AuthorizationRequest being returned
Sso.Application.CentralHandler: Debug: HandleChallenge with Location: https://localhost:44359/connect/authorize?client_id=SsoApplicationClient&scope=weatherforecasts.read%20weatherforecasts.write&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44384%2Fsignin-central&code_challenge=8Y5LgodB0uHMn0_GM9CmNYmqEYGfJz15EDSf2xaYfNg&code_challenge_method=S256&state=CfDJ8PC7ZLg_v2RDsl0VaXUuuT8NE8XSs1AYCpL2ZvWOHqXb3wfqoMRmAH4sn59F6H58d2TcUTPijfKCPrL9GlynS0MZJSfzQVchhFExl9Q9Qg_7J9qLr_TP-4z9tOeCcwFKDdl9O-_ecFuNc1SzWGb_DkgtPfFvVBwlIPahb4SChuHwhkHHynIVGxTUb8Xpdtmtpu2wXjq9vW-G_ShcEdRxWBQBCSqAtu3w2XDPEmtz1GwaGwhc68sZ38-PF2RW2WmrY_E1OK7mET9yfxK1Y0IAfH4I8KodEoK6sQohtOgVKrJKZLfu6H7ndhsON85jtELk1uEYZHHmHJq544ce1TkxQkN030XSHrDAIgIKZKEyb1Ft; and Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.central.ndfb5rjEd-gqaE4rKKeJb2DBQ2hTgf9U22nCZ6Day-U=N; expires=Mon, 15 Nov 2021 20:47:43 GMT; path=/signin-central; secure; samesite=none; httponly.
Sso.Application.CentralHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: central was challenged.
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter: Debug: Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter: Debug: Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Debug: Start authorize request
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint: Debug: No user present in authorize request
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Start authorize request protocol validation
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore: Debug: SsoApplicationClient found in database: True
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Trace: Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Debug: client configuration validation for client SsoApplicationClient succeeded.
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Checking for PKCE parameters
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found  identity scopes in database
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found weatherforecasts API resources in database
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found weatherforecasts.read, weatherforecasts.write scopes in database
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Debug: Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator: Trace: Authorize request protocol validation successful
```

Discodoc

```
{
  "issuer": "https://localhost:44359",
  "jwks_uri": "https://localhost:44359/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:44359/connect/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://localhost:44359/connect/token",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://localhost:44359/connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https://localhost:44359/connect/endsession",
  "check_session_iframe": "https://localhost:44359/connect/checksession",
  "revocation_endpoint": "https://localhost:44359/connect/revocation",
  "introspection_endpoint": "https://localhost:44359/connect/introspect",
  "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:44359/connect/deviceauthorization",
  "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "role",
    "weatherforecasts.read",
    "weatherforecasts.write",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "role"
  ],
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials",
    "refresh_token",
    "implicit",
    "password",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
  ],
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "token",
    "id_token",
    "id_token token",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token"
  ],
  "response_modes_supported": [
    "form_post",
    "query",
    "fragment"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
  ],
  "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
    "plain",
    "S256"
  ],
  "request_parameter_supported": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently I was missing the `UseAuthentication` middleware, but now it seems that the token returned from the IdentityServer don't contain any information