# IdentityServer4 - access token only contains sub claim

Tags: identityserver4, userinfo

I've finally been able to get an access token from IdentityServer, and [use it to retrieve the UserInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980731/identityserver4-signin-callback-returns-404-status-code-userinfo-endpoint-not/69988436#69988436).

However it seems that the access token I'm getting from IdentityServer only contains the `sub` claim.

Here is an example token

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVCOTBDN0JBNkExMjI2RjEyMEU0QzJGOEQzMjIwMzAxIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.MiDmgc7AzbVpogbp8ID3WvJ0eo4a30_taxR9EI9ylyJASSdOiNSsk-sGuW-YnJIzf668EQGkTym6FMIvOyTxem9DxxIs8nI_rboHLvuvj4e7CtJeELwbZyraZtAxjVjm9tn0BVRZxuskzb6XSq4xGrt2ag_E0Re5MeQOjtyL0EeMS5md5IEywfD7ThH7pIu8SofFvV5tAYbwO-OPd5YyqpPGKXslRtFlyc7lj9faQh-e2CRMql5rSwhJRqCiaIaLxvXk8ZwISfdhmuyzHA88xrzXkqTK_RElhq4PY_GqpRe64nMvIBrkSeoOGLzlQNE9wa58UypZFFV4l8Cpy3_P2Q
```

Here is the decoded token

[image: Decoded Bearer token received from IdentityServer]

I should be able to use this token to call the `/connect/userinfo` endpoint

[image: Response from /connect/userinfo]

And I can see this in the Output window:

```
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter: Debug: Request path /connect/userinfo matched to endpoint type Userinfo
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter: Debug: Endpoint enabled: Userinfo, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint for /connect/userinfo
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint: Debug: Start userinfo request
IdentityServer4.Validation.BearerTokenUsageValidator: Debug: Bearer token found in header
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint: Trace: Calling into userinfo request validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.UserInfoRequestValidator
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator: Trace: Start access token validation
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore: Debug: SsoApplicationClient found in database: True
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Trace: Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Debug: client configuration validation for client SsoApplicationClient succeeded.
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore: Debug: SsoApplicationClient found in database: True
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Trace: Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore: Debug: client configuration validation for client SsoApplicationClient succeeded.
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator: Debug: Calling into custom token validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomTokenValidator
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator: Debug: Token validation success
{
  "ValidateLifetime": true,
  "AccessTokenType": "Jwt",
  "ExpectedScope": "openid",
  "JwtId": "2FB8F8A941528DAF18D8C523BCC9A770",
  "Claims": {
    "nbf": 1637062004,
    "exp": 1637148404,
    "iss": "https://localhost:44359",
    "aud": "weatherforecasts",
    "client_id": "SsoApplicationClient",
    "central-theclient": "The SSO client",
    "sub": "959c9bfa-ed30-4638-9986-63cf1589eff8",
    "auth_time": 1637060908,
    "idp": "local",
    "jti": "2FB8F8A941528DAF18D8C523BCC9A770",
    "sid": "75C294FC15A544FE60E361B495EE5BCA",
    "iat": 1637062004,
    "scope": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "weatherforecasts.read",
      "weatherforecasts.write"
    ],
    "amr": "pwd"
  }
}
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint: Trace: Calling into userinfo response generator: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator: Debug: Creating userinfo response
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator: Debug: Scopes in access token: openid profile email weatherforecasts.read weatherforecasts.write
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found openid, profile, email identity scopes in database
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator: Debug: Requested claim types: 
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator: Information: Profile service returned the following claim types: 
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint: Debug: End userinfo request
```

You can even see my custom dedicated client claims being appended during the token validation.
But yet only the sub claim is returned from the identityserver userinfo endpoint...

How can I fix this?

### Edit

I added the `ProfileService`, and it's being called. But as Dejan already mentioned, `RequestedClaimTypes` is empty. However I updated the database by adding

```
[{"type":"email","identityResourceId":1003},{"type":"sub","identityResourceId":1003}]
```

records to the `IdentityResourceClaim` table. In the output window I can now see that the [`email` and `sub` claims are requested](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO/blob/master/Application/Sso.Application/CentralHandler.cs#L122):

```
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator: Debug: Token validation success
{
  "ValidateLifetime": true,
  "AccessTokenType": "Jwt",
  "ExpectedScope": "openid",
  "JwtId": "C37AF164BF3A7DE6A28FA7538683248F",
  "Claims": {
    "nbf": 1637069285,
    "exp": 1637155685,
    "iss": "https://localhost:44359",
    "aud": "weatherforecasts",
    "client_id": "SsoApplicationClient",
    "central-theclient": "The SSO client",
    "sub": "959c9bfa-ed30-4638-9986-63cf1589eff8",
    "auth_time": 1637067659,
    "idp": "local",
    "email": "pieterjan@example.com",
    "name": "Pieterjan",
    "jti": "C37AF164BF3A7DE6A28FA7538683248F",
    "sid": "BBFA9FD0A06824FA4E982DB1D3669A86",
    "iat": 1637069285,
    "scope": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "weatherforecasts.read",
      "weatherforecasts.write"
    ],
    "amr": "pwd"
  }
}
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint: Trace: Calling into userinfo response generator: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator: Debug: Creating userinfo response
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator: Debug: Scopes in access token: openid profile email weatherforecasts.read weatherforecasts.write
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore: Debug: Found openid, profile, email identity scopes in database
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator: Debug: Requested claim types: email sub
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator: Information: Profile service returned the following claim types: email name
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint: Debug: End userinfo request
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware: Trace: Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.UserInfoResult
```

The code finally enters the `ExternalLoginCallback`, but the `await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` returns null now.

The response from `https://localhost:44359/connect/userinfo` is

```
{
    "email": "pieterjan@example.com",
    "name": "Pieterjan",
    "sub": "959c9bfa-ed30-4638-9986-63cf1589eff8"
}
```

Comment: Inside the open id connect middleware, there should be token validation parameters you can set. Set NameClaimType to "name" and RolCalimType to "role"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The userinfo endpoint calls `GetProfileDataAsync` from `IdentityServer4.Services.IProfileService` to obtain the requested claim values. So the simple solution would be to implement that service.

Assuming you have your user manager defined as `IMyUserManager` and that it has the methods referenced here (`GetClaimsForUser` and `IsActive`), the simplified implementation might look like this:

```cs
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IMyUserManager userManager;

    public MyProfileService(IMyUserManager usermanager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        // context.RequestedClaimTypes will contain the claims you requested when invoking the token endpoint
        var myClaims = await userManager.GetClaimsForUser(context.Subject, context.RequestedClaimTypes);
        context.IssuedClaims = myClaims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        context.IsActive = await userManager.IsActive(context.Subject);
    }
}
```

You would then need to configure IdentityServer4 to use this implementation, by calling `AddProfileService` at startup like this:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
    // ...
    .AddProfileService<MyProfileService>();
```

I should also add that, in order for your wanted claim to be present in `context.RequestedClaimTypes`, it needs to be associated with the scopes you directly request when making a call to token endpoint.

At startup, when configuring IdentityServer4, make sure the identity resources you supplied to your `AddIdentityResources` call contains the required claim.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I implemented the ProfileService, but `signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` returns null now. I did some adjustments in the database already.

Comment: @Pieterjan I suggest you open a separate question regarding the external login stuff.

Comment: Well actually I'm already accustomed to Identity, I already implemented Facebook+Twitter+MS+Google login in my own apps. Only IdentityServer is new to me.

Comment: I can see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L656) that I need to have a `nameidentifier` claim returned from IdentityServer. However, I'll still have to find out how to add it through the database.

Comment: Hi. I asked a [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011619/nameidentifier-claim-is-required-for-external-login-to-succeed-how-to-remove-du)