# nameidentifier claim is required for external login to succeed. How to remove duplicate keys in token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims

I've finally managed to setup a project using IdentityServer4 to allow users to sign in with a single account into multiple apps. However, I feel like it's not completely as it should be.

This is my `OAuthOptions` class

```
public class CentralOptions : OAuthOptions
{
    public CentralOptions()
    {
        ClaimsIssuer = "https://localhost:44359";
        CallbackPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/signin-central");
        AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://localhost:44359/connect/authorize";
        TokenEndpoint = "https://localhost:44359/connect/token";
        UserInformationEndpoint = "https://localhost:44359/connect/userinfo";

        Scope.Add("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier");
        Scope.Add("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name");
        Scope.Add("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress");
        Scope.Add("openid");
        Scope.Add("profile");
        Scope.Add("email");
        Scope.Add("phone");
        Scope.Add("role");
        Scope.Add("weatherforecasts.read");
        Scope.Add("weatherforecasts.write");

        UsePkce = true;
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", "sub");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "name");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "email");

        //ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("sub", "sub");
        //ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("name", "name");
        //ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("email", "email");
    }
}
```

As you can see, right now I have to duplicate the `RequestedClaims`, once for the actual claim type, once for some shortname. I've been tweaking the contents of the database for some time, but can't figure out what I have to change to only have the claims once (I suppose that `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress` should not be present in the bearer token, and `email` should. But if I change the claims in the database and the application, the signin fails because it relies on [the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` claim to be present in the bearer token](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L676).

After I signed in, IS gives me an access token, for example:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVCOTBDN0JBNkExMjI2RjEyMEU0QzJGOEQzMjIwMzAxIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.KBKLezXnUs6s-bU9hme7Ab7ADZN8DEewqfUncDwR0c2_LFqAnyCw3IZ85VJC4t-NN6xJYu8ROk-cX9PDKIQzEAOWGkOrQuqeaspKfIpl_rCq4qbP7x7uflToqPO245iU6xlzxVnGuaG1o_sSILNQA_YZJV8nsmXJkdB2QonuCZwvrBh5URFXV5cZpivlWznJls9eqfRM9MjlRpWe-NCI6I7FExfCaRgPZ4b1XwyrmmQWNlaKJOmIM3qag1pQshdXBSzg3w65htj89zOKKWSNl6Go6Q_0pZzbv0FLcMUMR_GTzuw56_CFobavD40T65wQQlXxf0cfkzbrdyAx7k8tyg
```

Decoded it looks like this

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "5B90C7BA6A1226F120E4C2F8D3220301",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}
{
  "nbf": 1637179140,
  "exp": 1637265540,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44359",
  "aud": "weatherforecasts",
  "client_id": "SsoApplicationClient",
  "central-theclient": "The SSO client",
  "sub": "959c9bfa-ed30-4638-9986-63cf1589eff8",
  "auth_time": 1637179137,
  "idp": "local",
  "email": "pieterjan@example.com",
  "name": "Pieterjan",
  "id": "959c9bfa-ed30-4638-9986-63cf1589eff8",
  "phone": "+32123/45.67.89",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "Pieterjan",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "pieterjan@example.com",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/mobilephone": "+32123/45.67.89",
  "jti": "7F04A090371CD2460CBC879F70109553",
  "sid": "04463D9AD3D44B5A1A3BA4E973EA9928",
  "iat": 1637179140,
  "scope": [
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "phone",
    "role",
    "weatherforecasts.read",
    "weatherforecasts.write"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

With this token you can send a request to

```
https://localhost:44359/connect/userinfo
```

And this gives the following response

```
{
    "email": "pieterjan@example.com",
    "name": "Pieterjan",
    "id": "959c9bfa-ed30-4638-9986-63cf1589eff8",
    "phone": "+32123/45.67.89",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "Pieterjan",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "pieterjan@example.com",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/mobilephone": "+32123/45.67.89",
    "sub": "959c9bfa-ed30-4638-9986-63cf1589eff8"
}
```

It seems to me that you're supposed to have only shortname qualifiers in the response (`email`, `name`, `sub`, `phone`), is that correct? But if I rearrange this, the response from `/connect/userinfo` won't contain a `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name` claim, and the signin will fail at [following line](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L676) which looks for this exact claim in the response from this very UserInfo endpoint, and thus will fail.

I'm guessing I have to tweak the `OAuthOptions.ClaimActions` which currently read this:

```
ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", "sub");
ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "name");
ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "email");
```

I've been playing around with them already, but the slightest modification results in all claims no longer being returned from IdentityServer.

- [This is the place where IdentityServer is being configured](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO/blob/master/Central/Sso.Central.Data/Extensions/SsoCentralExtensions.cs#L24)

## dbo.Clients

[image: IdentityServer clients in database]

### dbo.ClientGrantType

= `client.allowedGrantTypes`

[image: Allowed grant-types for the SsoApplicationClient]

### dbo.ClientSecret

= `client.ClientSecrets`

[image: Client secrets]

### dbo.ClientScope

= `client.AllowedScopes`

[image: Allowed scopes for the SsoApplicationClient]

So here you see that right now I have scopes which probably shouldn't be in the database, since they're actually claim types, but if I remove them the `NameIdentifier` claim type will not be present in the Identity.

### dbo.ClientRedirectUri

= `client.RedirectUris`

[image: Authorized redirect urls for the SsoApplicationClient]

### dbo.ClientClaim

= `client.Claims`

[image: Claims returned by IdentityServer for each request to this client]

## dbo.IdentityResources

[image: Identity resources in the database]

### dbo.IdentityResourceClaim

= `identityResource.UserClaims`

Of which the markup reads:

```
List of associated user claims that should be included when this resource is requested.
```

[image: User claims for the identity resources]

So clearly here I had to introduce double lines for the external login to start working.

## dbo.AspNetUsers

[image: Users in my test database]

### dbo.AspNetUserClaims

= `user.Claims`

[image: Claims associated to the user at database level]

How can I setup my code and database correctly so that I no longer need those duplicate claims for my application to work/my external login to succeed?

Also, should the claims be persisted at database level, or [generated during login](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO/blob/master/Central/Sso.Central.Data/Services/AccountService.cs#L56)?

Thanks in advance.

[Git repository](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/SSO)

Comment: Why are you calling external login? Are you not logging in locally, to a local instance of IdentityServer4, using user name and password?

Comment: Thanks. Well the external login is being called from the demo application (SSO.Application = just some demo app consuming the OAuth client), not by the SSO application (SSO.Central).

Comment: Oh I think I was mislead. The `GetProfileDataAsync` method is being called 3 times, and only the third time the execution pointer returns to the `GetExternalLoginInfo` stack frame. That's when the claims are well loaded. I was probably reading the claims from the ClaimsPrincipal the first time `GetProfileDataAsync` was called.

Comment: You shouldn't use external login for that. You can redirect to central login page simply by returning `ChallengeResult` from your controller action. The challenge action result should be picked up by the authentication middleware, and handled by redirecting the user to the login page. Make sure you use `.AddOpenIdConnect` in your startup, not `.AddOAuth`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always consult IdentityServer4 samples when starting a new project involving it. You will want to check out the `MvcCode` sample client. You can also use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only use the shorter claim names in IdentityServer and do the necessary claims transformation or mapping in the client.

I would look at doing the transform in the client or API using the MapUniqueJsonKey:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("gender", "gender");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("birthdate", "birthdate");
```

I tink its important to understand what the ClaimsPrincipal user object contains after authentication (but before Authorization).

For more advanced transformation needs, then do take a look at using the IClaimsTransformation interface.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

More info:

- [Mapping, customizing, and transforming claims in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Am I correct that the `ClaimsActions` map the JSON keys from `/connect/userinfo` (which just litterally returns the contents of the `AspNetUserClaims` table`) to claims in the ClaimsPrincipal? I did try some modifications but this always results in no claims at all being returned...

Comment: The authentication handler takes in all the claims from the token and userinfo endpoint and then do the transformation. So it does not care where the claims came from. Also make sure the options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true; is set to true in the client, so that the client actually gets the details from the endpoint. You can verify this in Fiddler.